# draw Distributions Maps (double circles) in ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, symbology, maps

How can I draw Distributions Maps (double circles) in ArcGIS 10.1 ?

like this:

[image]

This map drawn in CorelDraw,it is shows the number of schools and the number of students in each Province (the circle with Vertical lines is the number of students,the circle with 
Horizontal lines is the number of schools).

So,I want to make this circles in ArcGIS (like the Divided circles in ArcGIS )

Comment: Interesting - I've never seen that kind of symbolisation, particularly for a distribution map - could you click 'edit' and add some description about the format and what you are trying to show?

Comment: I added some description

Comment: This appears to be two separate graduated or proportional symbols applied at the same time, showing only half of each symbol. The only way I can think you *might* be able to do this is using two layers with their own graduated/proportional symbology. You'd have to go deep into the symbol properties and maybe change to two different marker symbols each colored on a different half. And you may or may not be able to get them to line up at the bottom, or for that matter side to side without using an offset in the symbol. Note that style legend (stacked) can only be done manually in Arc.

Answer (score 1):

```
1.) prepare symbols:
- create a quadratic image, format png, e.g. 200x200px
- content: a half circle, color xyz
- rest of image: transparent
- save file as file a.png
- copy file to file b.png
- edit file b.png and change color of half-circle
2.) edit symbology:
- quantities, graduated symbol
- click on Template, edit symbol, type: picture marker symbol
- chose "a.png"
3.) copy layer
- edit symbol
- chose "b.png"
- apply "angle = 180"
```

Yozu may provide similar or different classifications or size-ranges.